# Android DataBase and cursor

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am trying to create a method to retrieve data from a table but I have a problem with the **Cursor** :

```
public ArrayList<Contenu> getTest(){

    ArrayList<Contenu> test = new ArrayList<Contenu>();

    String query = new String( "select valeur from table_contenu" );
    Cursor c = bdd.rawQuery( query , null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while (c.moveToNext())
    {
        Contenu contenu = new Contenu();
        contenu.setValeur(c.getString(c.getPosition ())); // bug
        test.add(contenu);
    }

    return test;
```

the log cat :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking into consideration Artoo Detoo answer you should also do the following

Change this:

```
c.moveToFirst();
while (c.moveToNext())
{
 ...
}
```

For this:

```
if(c != null)
{
    c.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        Contenu contenu = new Contenu();
        contenu.setValeur(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("valeur")));
        test.add(contenu);
    }while(c.moveToNext());
    c.close();
}
```

If not you will be skipping the first row.

Answer (score 2):

See this:

```
contenu.setValeur(c.getString(c.getPosition ())); // bug
```

It should be:

```
contenu.setValeur(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("valeur"))); // NO MORE BUG
```

Comment: getPosition don't need String args

Comment: I know... I'm using it! ;) and... yes, check if the cursor is null before moving to the first record.